# Issue in connecting to some specific remote machines from linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

Being in network. Consider my machine IP Address is 172.10.40.198 having CentOS. I am trying to connect to IP addresses 172.10.40.(200-203) which are installed as test vms with CentOS on Ubuntu machine. Another remote machine with IP address(172.10.40.205) having CentOS. I am able to ping my system through test vms and remote m/c(machine) but I am not able to do the reverse.

So, what my IT admin did. He logged into 172.10.40.2xx machines... Did ssh login as root to my machine. After ssh login, he was able to ping to 172.10.40.2xx. Then he did ssh login to all the machines i.e. 172.17.40.2xx . Then I was able to connect to 172.17.40.2xx machines remotely from my system i.e. 172.10.40.198. But this resolved my problem for short time. Next day or after few hours same problem I was facing....

Anybody is having a solution???

Comment: Are the routing tables correct on your host and the VM's host system?  What does `route -n` look like?

Comment: Also, which VM system are you using?  E.g., VirtualBox?  Are the VM iinterfaces NAT or bridged?

Comment: I am using **vmware** VM system. Interfaces on VM are bridged interfaces. Below was the output when I gave route -n command::   Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.17.40.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p6p1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 p6p1
0.0.0.0         172.17.40.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p6p1
**

Comment: Would you put the route info in your original post (so it looks better) for your machine, the host machine, and the VM?  When you ping or try to ssh, what's the exact error message?

Comment: Does IP forwarding need to be enabled on the host machine?

Comment: Does 172.17.40.254 have a route to 172.10.40.XXX?

Comment: I tried doing traceroute to 172.10.40.205.... It displayed traceroute to 172.17.40.205 (172.10.40.205), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *                         and when I gave command **traceroute** **172.10.40.205** nothing happened it gave :::::PING 172.10.40.205 (172.10.40.205) 56(84) bytes of data.

Comment: I'm sorry, but keeping track of the 'from' IP addresses and the 'to' IP addresses is confusing in the comments.  Would you edit your original post and add all this info, clearly showing where commands were run?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with firewalls.

All firewalls (and certainly iptables) have rules allowing all packets to pass if they belong to an **ESTABLISHED,RELATED** connection, something like this:

```
 iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

By connecting to your machine from one of the VMs, your sysadmin has exactly started a connection (from the firewall side), so that all packets from your machine back to the VMs are marked as ESTABLISHED,RELATED. After some time the connection stops, and the firewall does not recognize packets from you to belong to an ESTABLISHED,RELATED connection, and you are cut out.

I cannot say whether the firewall is on the VMs or on the host machine,

Comment: This is what I am getting when I gave command::"iptables -L" >>>>>>>                    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: On which machine?

Comment: Tried by turning off the firewall on both machines. It did not worked.